# BottomSheet Dialog opening more than one time

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I am using bottomsheetlayout pop up for social media sharing. now issue is , it is opening more than one time. please help me to solve this.

on my button click I call asynctask for download Images.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {
            super.onPostExecute(res);
            //prodImageUri1.addAll(prodImageUri);

            if(single_rdb.isChecked())
            {
                   createImageBitmap();
            }
            else if(allimg_rdb.isChecked())
            {

                 temps=new ArrayList<>();
                for(int i=0;i<prodImageUri.size();i++)
                {
                    if(i==8)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    temps.add(prodImageUri.get(i));
                   // System.out.println("SIZE "+temps.size()+"TEST1 "+temps.get(i));
                    createImageBitmap();

                }

            }

        }
```

here I call createImageBitmap method. now inside this method I have bottomsheet.show

```
 public void createImageBitmap(){
   ...................
   ...................
 if(single_rdb.isChecked())
        {
            header_image.setImageURI(prodImageUri.get(0));
            imageview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageview3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            horizontal_image_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else if(allimg_rdb.isChecked())
        {
            arrayListClone =  (ArrayList<Uri>) temps.clone();
            for(int i=0;i<arrayListClone.size();i++)
            {
               //System.out.println("FAFA"+arrayListClone);
                header_image.setImageURI(arrayListClone.get(i));
               // System.out.println("SIZE "+temps.size()+"TEST "+temps.get(i));
            }

            imageview1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageview2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageview3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            horizontal_image_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

         for(int i=0;i<arrayListClone.size();i++)
        {
            if(i==1)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("This is check");
            addPhotoBottomDialogFragment = new BottomSheetSharingFragment1();
            addPhotoBottomDialogFragment.show(((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "add_photo_dialog_fragment");
        }
```

What I am trying to achieve is, bottomDailog should open only one time, right now it is opening as per size of arraylist of Image. For Example if arraylist will have 3 images it shows dailog three time and placing on one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay remove the bottom sheet dialog call from your for loop and place it outside the for loop it's executing multiple times because of the for loop where until the for loop reaches the end of your array list it will keep executing.
So simply remove bottom sheet and place it outside the for loop 
You're facing problem because of this piece of code:

```
for(int i=0;i<prodImageUri.size();i++)
                {
                    if(i==8)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    temps.add(prodImageUri.get(i));
                   // System.out.println("SIZE "+temps.size()+"TEST1 "+temps.get(i));
                    createImageBitmap();

                }
```

so simply remove bottom sheet dialog from your createImageBitmap(); method and place it outside the method.

Comment: i tried with putting outside the loop, but it shows same result

Comment: remove that bottom sheet dialog from your createimagebitmap() method and place it outside the method

Comment: yes you are right i got your point, but where can i call this method? it will go out of the flow

Comment: keep the method as it is just remove the call for dialog and place it outside the method and all for loops

Comment: @khimji please consider marking my answer correct if it helped

Comment: your answer is right but as per suggestion i can not put it outside method, it is going out of app flow, and where should i put that code not getting properly